# How to concisely regex match any portion of a unique string?

Tags: regex, permutation, subset

**Context:**

Say I have a set of strings that are all distinct, though they may share starting sequences, i.e. `apple, banana, bpple, canana, applf`.

How best would I use a regex to match on a string that can contain any left-starting subset of *one of* those strings? For example `apple` and `banana` would obviously match. So would `banan`, `ba`, `bp` and `c`. `b` and `appl` would be ambiguous (and therefore should not match).

Using generated character classes in dynamically-built regexes (slow and ugly), I can make a match engine for this. However, it's complicated to the point that when I try, I end up doing most of the matching logic in Python/pick-your-language and ditching regex altogether. Is there some succinct way to make this work with regular expressions?

The simplest way to do this might be to break out each possible string (`apple, banana` etc) into a list and match against each one in sequence, but curiosity and stubbornness make me wonder if there isn't some way to do it with regex alone/primarily.

**TL;DR:**

Is there a way, using regex, to match: if and only if the string supplied is a **unique** and **left-starting** substring of **only one** of a given set of strings?

Comment: Any regex solution is going to be dynamically built; perhaps you could show the code you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions. You are asking for the leaves in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

If you absolutely have to use regular expressions, then they could be built like this:

```
(a(p(p(le?)?)?)?|b(a(n(a(na?)?)?)?)? ...)
```

It is easy to write some code that constructs this, but you won't be able to find out what actually matched (e. g. the user enters 'app' - you probably want to know that this matches 'apple'). Also, modifying this to ensure that there is no more than *one* match is really cumbersome. The code that constructs the regex will be much more complicated than just creating a trie (in fact, you probably have to create something equivalent to a trie in order to create the regex, you are asking for).