# Regex for words with pattern a$ ap$ app$ appl$ apple$

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a method to filter out words
I want to reduce the recursive filter with single regex

```
function filter(str){
    return str
       .replace(/a$/g, "")
       .replace(/ap$/g, "")
       .replace(/app$/g, "")
       .replace(/appl$/g, "")
       .replace(/apple$/g, "")
}
```

I was trying out the following regex `/ap?p?l?e?\$/g` but it matches with word like `ape$` which is not supposed to be filtered.

Comment: You could do `/a(?:p{1,2}|ppl|pple)?\$/g`

Comment: Or `a(?:p(?:p(?:l(?:e)?)?)?)?\$` https://regex101.com/r/ib5ICS/1 or `a(?:p(?:p(?:le?)?)?)?\$$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I like yours better :)

Comment: If you want to make it shorter and don't care about performance then `a(p(p(l(e)?)?)?)?\$` would work as well.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think you can also omit the group for `(e)?`, just `e?` will do it :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think you're right. Also, not sure what kind of data OP expects from  the `str` input but word boundaries may be relevant since we don't know if OP wants to target or omit stuff like `sap$` or `bapple$`. OP, thoughts?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You could ask for clarification from the OP if you want, or make a post out of it (but I do remember there are posts like these, I don't immediately know where though..)

Comment: yes I want to remove any string/substrings that matches with the regex. think it of as a invalid strings that I don't want.

Comment: @flash So `bapple$` should become just `b`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes

Comment: @MonkeyZeus and the `sap$` will become just `s`

Comment: Nice, so TheFourthBird's answer is all you need! `a(p(p(le?)?)?)?\$`

Comment: I think it might be a duplicate (without `\$`) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711572/how-to-concisely-regex-match-any-portion-of-a-unique-string

Answer (score -2):

You can use the regex below.

`/(a|ap|app|appl|apple)$/g`

So

```
function filter(str){
    return str
       .replace(/(a|ap|app|appl|apple)$/g, "")
}
```

Comment: This won't work, `$` is reserved for asserting position at the end of the line.